# Why is Apache fontbox not in maven central?

Tags: maven, fontbox

Does somebody know why Apache fontbox is not in maven central?

I looked here: https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.apache.fontbox

Is it possibly part of another package?

Comment: Are you sure your coordinates are correct? https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/fontbox

Comment: Oh, it's part of pdfbox... thank you...